# Is exists way to combine creation of html element and appening to target?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I often see code like:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');

$(element).appendTo([other element here]);
```

Is exists way to combine these two operations? And write something like:

```
[other element here].createElement('div');
```

Comment: Yes. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

`$(element).append('<div id="myNewElement"></div>')`

Comment: Thanks, your solution is the best, because you combine two operations and you have access to new element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('div').appendTo([other element here]);
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `appendTo()` returns the appended element, so you can chain directly from that, for example `$('div').appendTo(".container").css({ "width":50, "height":50 }).fadeIn();`

Comment: `$('div')` will select all <div> elements; what you want is `$('<div />').appendTo()`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're looking for:

```
$otherElement.append(document.createElement('div'));
```

Or have jQuery create the div

```
$otherElement.append($('<div />'));
```

In the above examples `$otherElement` is your existing jQuery object. Replace with a selector if needed e.g `$('#otherElement')`.

Comment: `.append($('<div />'));` is *superfluous*, `.append('<div />');` will do the same.

Comment: $otherElement.append($('<div />')); returns <div></div> ?

Comment: @user3775292 No.  See the answer by Resolution, using `appendTo()` if you want to return the new element.

Comment: @Yoshi the two are not superfluous, they do very different things.

Comment: Really? What's the difference, both create the div on-the-fly and append it?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you tagged the question with jQuery, yes jQuery has the [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) functions.

Using append() :

```
$(element).append('<div></div>');
```

Using appendTo() :

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo(element);
```

Comment: Didn't you see this 'Is exists way to combine these two operations' part of the question?

Comment: @BlankHead that's just two examples not *one* piece of code.